# Checkboxes using struts

Tags: struts

Hi I am willing to update the value of the checkbox , fetched from the Database, loaded on the JSP. I am creating a Employee Profile. The Jsp has fields Employee Name, Employee Address, Employee technical Skills.
The Employee Skills has following Checkboxes to select the following values

Checkbox1: Java   Checkbox2: Dot net

For a Employee X, Does not have both the computational skills Java and Dot net in the database. I am able to fetch the record from the database to the JSP.

In the action class I am fetching the values from the database and setting them into the EmployeeForm which has the two getters and setters. I am setting these values in request also with setattribute.

In the EmployeeUpdate.jsp I am doing the following

```
String skillsValue1=(String)request.getAttribute("C/C++");
String skillsValue2=(String)request.getAttribute("Java");

 <%if(skillsValue1!=null){ %>
         <html:checkbox property="ComputationalSkill1" value="C/C++"/>                     
           <%}else{ %>
              <html:checkbox property="ComputationalSkill1" value=" "/>  
                 <%}%>
            </td>          

<%if(skillsValue2!=null){ %>
         <html:checkbox property="ComputationalSkill2" value="Java"/>                     
           <%}else{ %>
              <html:checkbox property="ComputationalSkill2" value=" "/>  
                 <%}%>
            </td>
```

The following code displays the checkboxes perfectly for the employees with any of the above skills and without skills.

I am getting the following problem here

1. When I uncheck the value on any field, which was checked earlier , the value is setting to null in the bean perfectly. 
   But when When I Check the value on any field, which was not checked earlier(to update any of the fields), There is no value set in the bean for the particular property, neither null also.

Could anyone let me know how to get the changed values of a checkbox, i,e when I change the state from uncheck to check state, the value should be set in the property.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If an employee has the skill Java, you're displaying the following checkbox:

```
<html:checkbox property="ComputationalSkill2" value="Java"/>
```

This means that on submit, if the checkbox is checked, the following parameter will be sent:

```
ComputationalSkill2=Java
```

If an employee doesn't have the skill Java, you're displaying the following checkbox:

```
<html:checkbox property="ComputationalSkill2" value=" "/>
```

This means that on submit, if the checkbox is checked, the following parameter will be sent:

```
ComputationalSkill2=<blank space>
```

What you want is generate always the same checkbox (the first one), but preselect it if the employee has the skill Java, and not preselect it if the employee doesn't have the skill Java.

This is not possible as is using the `<html:checkbox>` tag, because it's supposed to be bound to a boolean property. So you could instead have a property `isJavaSkilled()`/`setJavaSkilled()` in your form bean, and use

```
<html:checkbox property="javaSkilled"/>
```

Struts will pre-select the checkbox if the form's javaSkilled property is true, and leave it unchecked if it's false.

Note however, that since you have a list of skills that can be or not present, you should instead have a property `getSkills()`/`setSkills()` of type `String[]`, and use a `<html:multibox>` tag.

Comment: I have a question, using the boolean isJavaSkilled()/setJavaSkilled() in the formbean, returns only the value true or false on Submit. I like to send the values Java and C/C++ depending on Submit, on checking the unchecked checkboxes.  Again I have two setters and getters for taking the two values, but using <html:checkbox property="javaSkilled"/> didnt worked out for the get and set to be string type. Could you please tell me how to handle this problem.

Comment: `<html:checkbox>` only supports boolean. That's documented. As I said in my answer, you should use an `<html:multibox>`

Comment: I have solved the issue Nizet by using onchange() function at <html:checkbox property="ComputationalSkill2" value=" "/>, which assigns values when the checkbox is checked and gives null value when not checked. But thanks for the solutions